# How do you specify a function type with multiple arguments in Haxe?

Tags: haxe

I'm trying to specify a function type to a function receiving two or more parameters.
For a function with one parameter it's easy:

```
var myFunction : Int -> Void;
```

You can reference a function like this with it:

```
function doSomething ( param1 : Int ) : Void { ... }
...
myFunction = doSomething;
```

But how do you reference a function with two or more parameters? Unfortunately there is still no complete [documentation](http://haxe.org/ref/type_advanced) about this.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Oh by the way, it IS documented

Comment: Where did you find the documentation? I haven't been able to find it yet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My Haxe is a bit rusty, but...

```
var myFunction : Int -> Int -> Void;
```

A function that takes two `Int` args and returns `Void`.

Comment: If you need to add a function as an argument just put that in parenthesis, something like: myFunction : (String -> Int -> Void) -> Void